# Tooltip for options in a select box is not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, select, html-select

In my project I'm using title tooltip for select option.
It is not working in Chrome. Please check with below example:

```html
<select>
    <option title="Option #1" value="1">Option #1</option>
    <option title="Option #2" value="2">Option #2</option>
    <option title="Option #3" value="3">Option #3</option>
</select>
```

Where is actual issue?

Comment: One thing you're missing is a closing `</select>`?

Comment: yes it is copy paste issue... can you please look into it. you do one thing .. make HTML file and add select box code and open it into chrome... you will see that tool tip on option item will not work.. but it is working in Internet explorer.

Comment: Please fix the code so it is exactly as you have it. You can also make a demonstration page for us at http://jsfiddle.net